# JAVASCRIPT Console data array to display in page

Tags: javascript, html, arrays, console

I have an array of data in the console from a football API, and I want to view the results of this array on divs inserted into the page, how can I do this?

My code is:

Html-

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Football API</h1>
  </div>
    <button type="button" onClick="getgames()">Check info</button>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Javascript-

```
async function getgames(){
    const settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://football-prediction-api.p.rapidapi.com/api/v2/predictions?market=classic&iso_date=2018-12-01&federation=UEFA",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "$APIKEY",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "football-prediction-api.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
    };

    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

I was thinking something of this sort to give me the input as a list of information:

```
const games = response;
let  = games.length;

let text = "<ul>";
for (let i = 0; i < games.lenght; i++) {
  text += "<li>" + games[i] + "</li>";
}
text += "</ul>";
```

How can I access this array in the console? Like, I said, each entry is i in array, then within i I want to get the information variables and display in divs...

Comment: You misspelled `length` here: `games.lenght`

Comment: The script can't access data in the console. It should just use the `response` variable in the `.done()` function.

Comment: so, point being @Barmar is that the array it outputs should be presented in page, I know its possible, know how?

Comment: Put the code you show inside the `.done(function(response) ...)` and then assign it to `.innerHTML` of the element where the list should be shown.

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
</head>
<body>
  <div class="page-header">
    <h1>Football API</h1>
  </div>
  <div id="fetch"></div> // **fetched data will be added here**
    <button type="button" onClick="getgames()">Check info</button>
<script src="js/main.js"></script>
</body>
</html>

    async function getResponse() {
        const response = await fetch(
            'here use your API,
            {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: {
                    'x-rapidapi-host': 'Your host',
                    'x-rapidapi-key': 'your_api_key'
                }
            }
        );
        const data = await response.json(); // **Extracting data as a JSON Object from the response**
}
```

**then loop through the resonsed data which is a object .**

```
let fetched=document.getElementById("fetch")
for (const key in data){
  if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
    let new=document.createElement("li")
    new.innerHTML=data[key]
    fetched.appendChild(new)
  }
}
```

Comment: posted reply as answer

Answer (score 0):

Does this work?

```
async function getgames(){
    const settings = {
        "async": true,
        "crossDomain": true,
        "url": "https://football-prediction-api.p.rapidapi.com/api/v2/predictions?market=classic&iso_date=2018-12-01&federation=UEFA",
        "method": "GET",
        "headers": {
            "X-RapidAPI-Key": "$APIKEY",
            "X-RapidAPI-Host": "football-prediction-api.p.rapidapi.com"
        }
        };
    const data = await response.json();
    
    let fetched=document.getElementById("fetch")
    for (const key in data){
      if(obj.hasOwnProperty(key)){
        let new=document.createElement("li")
        new.innerHTML=data[key]
        fetched.appendChild(new)
      }
    }
        
    $.ajax(settings).done(function (response) {
        console.log(response);
    });
}
```

or how should I lay the pieces?

Comment: Don't put API keys in your code/examples on StackOverflow. RapidAPI assigns API keys privately to individuals and this is a public site.

Comment: Was a mistake.. my bad